# primeng radio button how to change checked

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNg radio buttons. By default it is not checked. I want to be able programmatically using javascript or typescript to check the radio button.

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
<p-radioButton inputId="taken" id="taken" name="groupname" value="true"  class="col-sm-3 pl-3"  [(ngModel)]="modalTaken"></p-radioButton>
```

```html
document.getElementById("taken").checked=true;
```

I would expect to be able to change the radio button to check. As it work in normal radio button(not primeng radio button).

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<p-radioButton inputId="taken" id="taken" name="groupname" value="true" label='true' class="col-sm-3 pl-3"  [(ngModel)]="modalTaken"></p-radioButton>
```

**TS:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  modalTaken = 'true';
}
```

your `modalTaken` has to match the value of your radio button. If you have had a radio button with the value `value='dog'` your `modalTaken='dog'` should look like that.